# How do you loop through and print a multidimensional array in a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, view

I'm using the ancestry gem, and would like to print out an entire tree into a table. The object I'm working with is groups, so it'd look something like this.

```
Group A
|__ Group A 1
    |__ Group A 1 A
|__ Group A 2
    |__ Group A 2 A
    |__ Group A 2 B
Group B
Group C
|__ Group C 1
```

Typically, I'd create a method and call itself within the loop, but that would seem to break MVC convention. Within the view, how would I output the object/hash?

Note: Ancestry has a method to convert the ActiveModel group to a hash, so that is an option rather than iterating through the ActiveModel object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use a loop within your view, and that's exactly the way you'd want to do it:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <!-- Render stuff -->
  <% group.groups.each do |child| %>
    <!-- Render child stuff -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It may be a lot easier to manage if you do this using partials instead:

```
# view.html.erb
<% render partial: 'group', collection: @groups, as: :group %>

# _group.html.erb
<!-- Render stuff -->
<% render partial: 'first_child', collection: group.groups, as: :group %>
```

Check out the [Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) section of the Rails guide on [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for some more info.

---

**EDIT**: If you need to handle an unknown level of nesting, partials would work here too. You can even track the depth if you want. Say you wanted to display them using nested `ul` elements:

```
# _group.html.erb
<% content_tag :li, class: "depth-#{depth}" do %>
  <!-- Any output needed for the group itself -->
  <% unless group.group.empty? %>
    <ul>
      <%= render partial "group", collection: group.groups, as: :group,
              locals: { depth: depth+1 } %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# In your view file
<ul>
  <% render partial "group", collection: @groups, as: :group,
         locals: { depth: 0 } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the objects are of unknown depth. If I use this method, I only get two levels of output. It isn't the loop I'm trying to avoid, it's the self-referencing method that I think would break MVC convention.

Comment: If they all need to get rendered the same way, then you could use the identical partial recursively, in which case is should handle any depth. Will update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I like this solution. It gives me more freedom over the html. Do I gain anything by using content_tag instead of being more direct '<tr class="<%=...'?

Comment: It's mostly personal preference, and I tend to use both. The advantage of using `content_tag` is that I think it's easier when you have a lot of dynamic stuff happening in the tag. Chucking `<%= ... %>` everywhere is fine, and I'll use it if I'm just throwing in strings from elsewhere, but as I soon as I get any logic I find it tends to be a bit neater using `content_tag`.

Comment: I can't for the life of me get the partial to render with the collection "group", which should be right. Any suggestions? : `<% group.children.each do |group| %><%= render partial: "groups/nested_group", collection: group, locals: { depth: 0 } %><% end %>`

Comment: You're using the `:collection` option incorrectly -- you should pass that a collection, and it will render the partial for each object in that collection. In this case, you're passing it an individual object. So you either want only `<%= render partial: "groups/nested_group", collection: group.children, locals: { depth: 0 } %>`, or `<%= group.children.each do |g| %><%= render partial: "groups/nested_group", locals: { group: g, depth: 0 } %><% end %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a proc.  This is a recursion problem.

```
array_printer = Proc.new do |set| 
  set.map {|elem| (elem.is_a? Array) ? array_printer(elem) : "<td>#{elem}</td>" }
end

puts array_printer master_set
```

Comment: which, actually, I didn't solve well.  I'll have to come back later and edit this.  hope it helps in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

I'd just write a helper to do it.

```
def render_tree(groups)
  content_tag(:ul) do
    groups.map do |group|
      content_tag(:li) do
        content_tag(:div, group.name, class: "groupname") +
        render_tree(group.children)
      end
    end.join
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= render_tree @your_tree %>
```

Style as desired.

Comment: I'm trying this solution out. Is there a syntactic issue by chance in the provided code? A missing } or too many ends?

I apologize for the rudimentary inquiry - I'm new to ruby.

Comment: Very possibly, I didn't test it. I did mismatch a { with an end; I'll fix that.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: undefined method `join' for "<ul></ul>":ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer

Any suggestions? (Thanks again, btw)

Comment: Make sure you're joining an array (the result of #map will be one). It looks like you have the .join one level too far and are trying to join the string output of content_tag(:ul).